# Access SipFactory from EJB

Tags: java, servlets, ejb, jboss7.x, mobicents-sip-servlets

I'm using Mobicents SipServlets 2.1.547 with JBoss AS 7.2.0. I need to inject the SipFactory into an EJB and I'm using the @Resource annotation, which always results in a NullPointerException when I try to access the SipFactory. At this point I have `@Resource SipFactory sf` in my bean.
Is there any reason why this wouldn't work? What would be the correct way to inject the SipFactory so I can access it from my bean?

**UPDATE:** I set the mapped name in the @Resource annotation, and now JBoss is giving me the following error on deployment:

```
JBAS014775:    New missing/unsatisfied dependencies:
  service jboss.naming.context.java.jboss.java:sip."com.mycompany.testproject.testapp".SipFactory (missing) dependents: [service jboss.naming.context.java.module.test."test-sip-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT".env."com.mycompany.testproject.testapp.ManagerBean".sf]
```

ManagerBean.java:

```
@Resource(mappedName="java:sip/com.mycompany.testproject.testapp/SipFactory")
private SipFactory sf;
```

sip.xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
<sip-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.jcp.org/xml/ns/sipservlet http://www.jcp.org/xml/ns/sipservlet/sip-app_1_1.xsd" version="1.1">
 <display-name>TEST SIP Servlet</display-name>
 <description>TEST SIP Servlet</description>
 <app-name>com.mycompany.testproject.testapp</app-name>

<servlet-selection>
    <main-servlet>
        TestServlet
    </main-servlet>
</servlet-selection>

 <servlet>
  <servlet-name>TestServlet</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>com.mycompany.testproject.testapp.TestServlet</servlet-class>
  <init-param>
     <param-name>servertest</param-name>
     <param-value>sip:siptest@127.0.0.1:5080</param-value> 
  </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
 </servlet>
 <session-config>
  <session-timeout>1</session-timeout>
 </session-config>
</sip-app>
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try with setting the mapped name ?
Something similar to this piece of code below where you replace the appname part with your appname from sip.xml deployment descriptor.

```
@Resource(mappedName="java:sip/appname/SipFactory")
private SipFactory sipFactoryResource;
```

Comment: Hi Jean, thanks for answering. I did try to set the mapped name, which resulted in a JBoss error during deployment, so I guess that's the source of the problem. The error is the following:

`JBAS014775:    New missing/unsatisfied dependencies:
 service jboss.naming.context.java.jboss.java:sip.Smsfapp.SipFactory (missing) `

I double checked my app name in the sip.xml and that part seems to be correct. I assume I'm missing something in the sip.xml? Thanks for your support.

Comment: Can you retry with one more recent build from https://mobicents.ci.cloudbees.com/job/MobicentsSipServlets-Release/ ? Also if you can upload a sample application EAR with war and source code reproducing the problem that would be great

Comment: Sure, I'll try to put together a sample app that reproduces the error and let you know.